# TypeError: combo.getSelection (...) is null in the render event. Extjs 6

Tags: javascript, extjs

In the Ext.window.Window component, I use the combobox field:

```
Ext.define('BookApp.view.BookEdit', {
extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
alias: 'widget.bookwindowedit',  
layout: 'fit',
autoShow: true,
store: 'BookStore',
modal   : true,
initComponent: function() {
    var me = this;
    me.myStates = Ext.data.StoreManager.get('States').load();    
    me.items = [{
            xtype: 'form',
            items: [                
            {
                xtype: 'combobox',
                fieldLabel: 'Статус',
                name: 'status',
                store: me.myStates,
                valueField: 'name',
                displayField: 'name',
                typeAhead: true,
                queryMode: 'remote',                    
                listeners: {
                            'select': function (combo, records) {
                                index = records.internalId;

                                filterCombo(combo, index);
                            },              

                       'boxready': function () {
                     console.log("form's boxready");    
                    index =       combo.getSelection().internalId;
                      filterCombo(combo, index);
                        }
                    }
            },             
            ]
        }];
    me.buttons = [{
            text:'Save',
            iconCls:'save-icon',
            action: 'save'
    },
    {
            text: 'Clear',
            scope: this,
            action: 'clear'
    }
    ];

    me.callParent(arguments);
}
});   



function filterCombo(combobox, index) {
            store = combobox.getStore();
            store.clearFilter();
            store.filterBy(
                function(record) {
                    if ((record.data.order_install == index - 1)  || (record.data.order_install == index + 1)) {
                        return true;
                    } else {
                       return false;
                    }
                }
            );
        };
```

When an attempt is made in the listeners of the render event to get an index entry, an error occurs:

> TypeError: combo.getSelection (...) is nul

Why can an error occur and how to get index entries correctly?
When adding a boxready event to get records, this event does not work.

Answer (score 1):

As you are using your definition of "**initComponent**" make sure you call 
`"this.callParent()"` 
at the end of definition of "initComponent". 
At the time when "**render**" event is fired there wont be any selection hence you'll get empty array.
Explicitly set selection by something like "combo.setSelection(0)".

Comment: Yes, at the end of the "initComponent" there is me.callParent (arguments);
How in my case in 'render' is it correct to get internalId to pass it to the filterCombo function? I corrected my question

Comment: Change the event from "render" to something like "boxready" then you'll get some value for "getSelection", given there is some default selection.And more over when there is filtering already in "select" event I don't think it is necessary to do in "render" event.

Comment: changed 'render' to 'boxread' but it doesn't work. Corrected in the question

Comment: My point is it is working as expected i.e it'll return null, because there won't be any selection on combo box at the beginning.If you want selection at beginning then you need to set selection in explicitly.